# Protestant denominations that reject solas?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism, sola-fide, sola-scriptura, sola-gratia

Historically, the five *Solae* have been a divider between Catholic and Protestant theologies. Yet, I can't help but notice that most denominations do not believe in the "alone" taken in its fullest sense. For example, The Methodist church does not believe in *sola scriptura,* but instead *[prima scriptura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prima_scriptura).*  Are there other Protestant denominations which reject some or all of the *solae?*

Comment: Asking for a list of denominations is too broad. And this ultimately comes down to differing opinions of what those terms mean - I've heard *sola scriptura* taught in several contexts, but always with an equivalent meaning to your *prima scriptura*.

Comment: It totally depends on how you define Protestant. See http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/39419/is-non-catholic-non-orthodox-modern-western-denomination-an-ok-definition-of-p/39425#39425

Comment: See also [What is the background against which Prima Scriptura was defined?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/68278/6071)

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that Methodist don't accept sola scriptura, but instead prima scriptura. Not only that, they also reject sola fide. That is because they teach synergism. Now, I do know some Pentecostals also hold to synergism, and therefore reject sola fide. Also, if you consider Anglicanism to be Protestant (which most don't, but they are related) there are multiple opinions among them. They're seperated between high church, broad church and low church. Each tradition gets either more Protestant or Catholic in its theology. Now, rejecting all the solas would probably disqualify you as a Christian; sola gratia (grace alone) is something all Christian denominations teach regardless if they are Catholic, Protestant, Eastern Orthdox, etc. Ultimatly, with the 40,000 different kinds of Protestants out there, it can get really diverse.

Comment: I don't see how synergism would contradict sola fide.

Comment: @juhani Synergism would not contradict Sola Fide,  it contradicts Sola Gracia.  Sola Fide co contradicts Scripture all together and is a conception of men. "ORATE OTI EX ERGON DIKAIOUTAI ANTHROPOS KAI OUK EK PISTOS MONO." or " for one in justified by works and not by faith alone".

Comment: Since *sola gratia* is not stated in Scripture itself, it is perfectly possible to be a Christian while rejecting it. The *solas* were a Protestant formulation against Roman Catholicism.

Comment: Neither is the doctrine of the trinity, but I think even Catholics would agree that you will not be saved if you do not believe that doctrine. I'm not sure that appealing to sola scriptura to refute sola gratia does anything but undermine a full rejection of the solas.

Comment: @JamesShewey For there are three that bear record in heaven, the Father, the Word, and the Holy Ghost: and these
three are one. 1 John 5:7

Comment: @JamesShewey To be more specific, contrary to what is stated in this answer, not all Christian denominations teach *sola gratia.* I happen to belong to a Christian denomination that does not teach *sola gratia.* It is common for Christians to think "all Christians believe" the particular doctrines they happen to believe. Such generalizations make for poor answers on Christianity.SE.

Comment: @Juhani The [Comma Johanneum](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/39889/is-1-john-57-8-the-comma-johanneum-a-latin-corruption) in 1 John 5:7-8 was almost certainly added to the text well after the doctrine of the Trinity had already been formulated and adopted by the Roman Catholic Church.

Comment: @LeeWoofenden That's not true. You can quite easily find defenses of it on the Internet. [This](http://www.studytoanswer.net/bibleversions/1john5n7.html#greek) and [this](http://brandplucked.webs.com/1john57.htm) for example.

Comment: @Marc Assuming you quote James 2:24, [this](http://www.wordofhisgrace.org/jamesworksqa.htm) article gives an explanation of it.

Comment: @Juhani There will always be defenders of minority positions--especially when it affects church doctrine. But this is a side issue anyway. The question isn't even about the Trinity.

Comment: @LeeWoofenden Concerning sola gratia, what about Ephesians 2? Doesn't it teach sola gratia, sola fide and solo Christus?

Comment: @Juhani The comments here really aren't for the purpose of debate. They're to improve questions and answers.

Comment: I would be happy to address the issues of James and Ephesians in chat with anyone. for that matter the whole book of Romans.  The fact is that it is explicitly stated that we are not justified by faith alone and in no place, not even in the smallest degree is it stated that we are saved by Faith alone.  It is contrary to the Nature of God, the initial state of Justice or Rightousness "DIKAIOUTAI" alien to salvation history and in no way foreshadowed in the history of Salvation.

Comment: Chat started [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23216/protestant-denominations-that-reject-solas) for anyone interested